# Stay on page if async call errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have an async method that calls an API, then if the response returned is a PDF, it returns the file

If the response is NOT a pdf (ie: a JSON object with an error value), how can I stay on the current page and simply display the error message?

The application is underpinned by Umbraco and it currently sets the ViewBag and then returns RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage which means the page displays only the JSON object

```
public async Task<ActionResult> QuotationPdfAsync(DbCalculationInput calculation)
        {
            var content = await _apiClient.QuotationAsync(calculation);
            if (content.HasPdf)
            {
                var fileName = $"{calculation.CalculationName}_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}_{DateTime.Now:HHmmss}.pdf";
                return this.File(content.Pdf, "application/pdf", fileName);
            }

            this.ViewBag.FormError = content.ErrorResponse.FailureDescription;
            return this.RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> QuotationPdfAsync(DbCalculationInput calculation)
    {
        var content = await _apiClient.QuotationAsync(calculation);
        if (content.HasPdf)
        {
            var fileName = $"{calculation.CalculationName}_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}_{DateTime.Now:HHmmss}.pdf";
            return this.File(content.Pdf, "application/pdf", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ViewBag.FormError = content.ErrorResponse.FailureDescription;
            return Json("So and so error..");  
        } 
        return this.RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
```

Comment: The `return this.RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage()` is unreachable. How does returning the JSON in the else refresh the current page?

Comment: You stay on the same page. 
and in the client you can an error using Ajax or any other way. instead of presenting pdf .
or redirecting. I actually didn't know what an UmbracoPage was.. 
Now that iv'e read about it, it seems like what your did should work.